# Edit extraPortMappings in kind cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kind

I've scanned through all resources, still cannot find a way to change `extraPortMappings` in Kind cluster without deleting and creating again.

Is it possible and how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not said explicitly in the official docs, but I found some references that confirm: your thoughts are correct and changing `extraPortMappings` (as well as other cluster settings) is only possible with recreation of the kind cluster.

> if you use extraPortMappings in your config, they are “fixed” and
> cannot be modified, unless you recreate the cluster.

[Source - Issues I Came Across](https://blog.devgenius.io/updating-kind-kubernetes-api-certificate-after-reboot-1521b43f7574)

> Note that the cluster configuration cannot be changed. The only
> workaround is to delete the cluster (see below) and create another one
> with the new configuration.

[Source - Kind Installation](https://10clouds.com/blog/kubernetes-environment-devs/)

> However, there are obvious disadvantages in the configuration and
> update of the cluster, and the cluster can only be configured and
> updated by recreating the cluster. So you need to consider
> configuration options when you initialize the cluster.

[Source - Restrictions](https://www.programmersought.com/article/12347371148/)